# Possible paths between nodes

Tags: graph-theory, path-connected

How many simple paths are there from S to F, where in a simple path, all edges are distinct. My solution is brute-force, but could not find exact value for the possible number of paths. Is there any clever idea (maybe application of P-NP) instead of direct calculation?

Note: If there is an online platform where it can be calculated directly, please refer to that in the comment or answer section.[image]

Comment: Is there any idea on solving this problem? Any approach or suggestion is strongly welcomed!

Comment: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20246/counting-the-number-of-simple-paths-in-undirected-graph

Comment: join the cstheory community and ask there, it is more computer science oriented

Comment: I also posted there, but still need advice from this community as well

Comment: @ombk Moreover, your provided link is not the exact problem. Here, I allow cycles to be used, only edges are not used twice!

Comment: hehe not my field of expertise, but would love to know the answer.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3922889/14578, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/47919/5038, https://stackoverflow.com/q/65016790/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: @ombk, if you are going to suggest another site, may I request that you let the person know to avoid cross-posting on multiple sites?  You can suggest they delete the copy here before posting elsewhere.  I'm hoping this will lead to a better experience for all. Thank you for listening and considering it!